# "Unknown class BarChartView in Interface Builder file" error when using a custom framework

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios-charts

I am trying to use the `Charts framework` in my app. I have build the binary for this using Carthage and added to my app and contains two files:

```
 - Charts-Swift.h
 - Charts.h
```

Then I have set the custom class of a view to `BarChartView`, but it seems that XCode doesn't recognize the class (No autocomplete). And the custom module is not set also.

When I run the app I always get this warning:

```
Unknown class BarChartView in Interface Builder file
```

I have try some solutions from the internet, but nothing seems to work for me.
Anyone has a solution for `Xcode 8.1` and `Swift 3` ?

Comment: Is this steps followed : Charts now include Carthage prebuilt binaries.

github "danielgindi/Charts" == 3.0.0
github "danielgindi/Charts" ~> 3.0.0
In order to build the binaries for a new release, use carthage build --no-skip-current && carthage archive Charts && carthage archive ChartsRealm.

Comment: I tried that now, but apparently there is a problem with Carthage when building (https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/560). Maybe I should use Cocoapods.

Comment: @Kobe Did you solve this ? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @strangfeld: I used Cocoapods to build the library instead of Carthage

Comment: @Kobe: Frustrating but I did the same in the meantime. Nevertheless thank you very much for responding.

Comment: @Kobe when you used cocoapods, did you still have the header files? What did you put as the `Module` in interface builder?

Comment: @AdamJohns: I put Charts, as a module.

Answer (score 15):

You just need inform IB where the class comes from, by specifying the module 'Charts'.

[image: 'Charts']